# Manipulate urls with regular expressions instead of the slip approach

Tags: javascript, regex, url, split

Basically I have an url which looks like this structurally speaking:

`http://www.my-site.com/topic1/topic2/topic3/topic4/topic5`

and I want to do 2 things to it:

```
1. check the structure and validate it
2. replace both topic3 and topic4 with a new parameters called topic6
```

This is my solution for now but I am interested to build something more optimize.

```
if ((url.match(/\//g) || []).length === 7) {
    const arr = url.split('/');
    const topic5 = arr.pop();
    arr.pop();
    arr.pop();
    arr.push('topic6', topic5);
    return arr.join('/');
}
```

So as you can see, for the fact that I am not very good at regular expressions I have used another approach which doesn't look that good. I basically check for the number of `/` in the string, if tey are 7 it means that the structure of the url is good and that on this type of url I should apply the next steps. After that I grab the last param of the url and also remove it and next after that I remove the last 2 parameters and add the new one instead along with the `topic5`.

In case you you have a better approach, please let me know. I think that it can be done by writing less number of lines of code but as I said, I am not very familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: If your code works well and there is no issue, please consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Comment: True, I did not know about that channel. I guess the only issue is that there you don't have a big community. For example here there are 213778 followers for regex keyword while there are only 700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use replace to match last 3 with `/`, capture only the last `/` part in capture group and replace with the `topics6 and value of captured group`

[image]

```js
let url = "http://www.my-site.com/topic1/topic2/topic3/topic4/topic5"

let func = (url) => {
  if ((url.match(/\//g) || []).length === 7) {
    const arr = url.replace(/(?:\/[^\/]+){2}(\/[^\/]+)$/, (m, g) => `\/topics6${g}`)
    return arr
  }
  return url
}

console.log(func(url))
```

Comment: Hello. It seems that it returns http://www.my-site.com/topic1/topic2/topic3/topics6/topic5 and it should return http://www.my-site.com/topic1/topic2/topics6/topic5

Comment: @paulalexandru [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/8dwv4Q/1/) isn't it what you're after ?

Comment: Yes I do, but before your second edit you said in the comment (?:[^\/]+){2}(\/[^\/]+)$ which did not work also. The last change /(?:\/[^\/]+){2}(\/[^\/]+)$/ seem to work. Thanks

Comment: @paulalexandru i was on phone, my bad for missing that `\/`